# A* search in C: implementation and performance on graph map

Tags: c, performance, dictionary, graph, a-star

I'm writing a "game" project for a course using an "implicit" rapresentation of a Graph: I have a matrix of N*M items defined like that:.

```c
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int k;      //value of the position
    int ID;
    bool path;  //temporary field used to print the path
} VCOORD;

typedef struct gObj {
    //numero vertici
    int             vNum;           //number of vertices

    VCOORD  **      maze;           //pointer to implicit maze
    int             width;          //width of the maze
    int             height;         //height of the maze

    //function pointers
    struct gObj *   ( *build)           ( struct gObj *, int );
    Set *           ( *getAdjList )     ( struct gObj *graph, int u );

    void            ( *insertEdge )     ( struct gObj *, int , int , int  );
    void            ( *insertVertex )   ( struct gObj *graph );

    int             ( *getWeight )      ( struct gObj *, int, int );
    int             ( *transpose )      ( struct gObj *graph );
    int         *   ( *path)            ( struct gObj *, int , int );
} GRAPHOBJ;
```

I've implemented:

BFS, Dijkstra, A*

BFS and Dijkstra works fine, but i have some problem with A*

A* (A Star)

```c
int *a_star ( GRAPHOBJ *graph, int s, int t ) {
    int x, y, i;
    int cost;
    bool found = false;
    void    *   tmp;                    //used to store Heap first element
    Set     *   AdjList     = NULL;     //Adjiacence list implemented as queue
    Set     *   closed      = NULL;     //Closed set implemented as queue
    Heap    *   open        = NULL;     //Open set implemented as Heap
    int     *   pred        = ( int *) malloc ( graph->vNum * sizeof ( int ) );

    int g[graph->vNum];                 //g distance function
    int f[graph->vNum];                 //f distance function

    //initialization
    for ( i = 0; i < graph->vNum; i++ ) {
        f[i]        = INFINITE;
        g[i]        = 0;
        pred[i]     = NIL;
    }
    f[s] = heuristic ( graph, s, t );
    open = initializeHeap ( minHeapify );
    insert ( open, new_HeapData ( s, 0 ) );

    while ( !isHeapEmpty ( open ) && found == false ) {

        //extracting the first Object of the Heap ( Open )
        tmp     = extractFirst ( open );
        //pushing the node into the Closed set
        push ( closed , setInt ( x ) );
        //get the int number from the extracted Object
        x       = getData ( tmp );
        //get the ditance f from the extracted Object
        f[x]    = getKey ( tmp );

        //debug
        if ( PRINTALL ) graph->maze[getCoord ( graph, x )->y][getCoord ( graph, x )->x].path = true;
        //printf ("x: %d ", x);
        if ( x == t ) {
            found = true;
        } else {

            AdjList = graph->getAdjList ( graph, x );

            while ( !isEmpty ( AdjList ) ) {
                //getting the first element of the adj. list
                y               = getInt ( getFront ( AdjList ) );
                //graph->getWeight refers to getMatrixWeight
                g[y]            = g[x] + graph->getWeight ( graph, x, y );
                cost            = g[y] + heuristic ( graph, y, t );

                //checking if y is in the open set
                bool yInOpen    = heapIntSearch ( open, y );
                //checking if y is in the closed set
                bool yInClosed  = intSearch ( closed , y );

                if ( yInOpen && cost < f[y] ) { // case 1
                    decreaseKey ( open, y, cost );
                } 

                else if (  yInClosed && cost < f[y] ) { // case 2
                    deleteFromSet ( closed, y );
                    insert ( open, new_HeapData ( y, cost ) );
                }

                else if ( !yInClosed && !yInOpen ) { // case 3
                    insert ( open, new_HeapData ( y, cost ) );
                }
                AdjList = dequeue ( AdjList );
                if ( pred[y] == NIL )
                    pred[y] = x;
            }
        }           
    }
    pred[s] = NIL;
    printf ("\n\n");
    return pred;
}
```

Heuristic Function, with euclidian/manhattan distance:

```c
int heuristic ( GRAPHOBJ *graph, int s, int t ) {
    VCOORD *    start       = getCoord ( graph, s );
    VCOORD *    target      = getCoord ( graph, t );
    /*manhattan*/return ( abs ( start->x - target->x ) + abs ( start->y - target->y ) );
    /*euclidian*///return pow ( pow ( ( target->x - start->x ), 2 ) + pow ( ( target->y - start->y ), 2 ), 0.5 );
}
```

Edge Weight Function:

```c
int getMatrixWeight ( GRAPHOBJ *graph, int u, int v ) {
    int weight = 1;
    return weight;
}
```

the Adjiacence list implementation ( NORTH, SOUTH, etc are macros to decrease/increase the coordinate:

```c
Set *getAdjList ( struct gObj *graph, int u ) {
    Set *Adj = NULL;
    int x = u % graph->width;
    int y = u / graph->width;
    int neighbor;

    if ( NORTH(y) > 0 && graph->maze[NORTH(y)][x].k != 9 ) {
    //if ( NORTH(y) > 0 ) {
        neighbor = graph->width * ( NORTH(y) ) + ( x );
        Adj = enqueue ( Adj, setInt ( neighbor ) );
    }
    if ( EAST(x) < graph->width && graph->maze[y][EAST(x)].k != 9  ) {
    //if ( EAST(x) < graph->width  ) {
        neighbor = graph->width * ( y ) + ( EAST(x) );      
        Adj = enqueue ( Adj, setInt ( neighbor ) );
    }
    if ( SOUTH(y) < graph->height && graph->maze[SOUTH(y)][x].k != 9 ) {
    //if ( SOUTH(y) < graph->height ) {
        neighbor = graph->width * ( SOUTH(y) ) + ( x );     
        Adj = enqueue ( Adj, setInt ( neighbor ) );
    }
    if ( WEST(x) > 0 && graph->maze[y][WEST(x)].k != 9 ) {
    //if ( WEST(x) > 0 ) {
        neighbor = graph->width * ( y ) + ( WEST(x) );      
        Adj = enqueue ( Adj, setInt ( neighbor ) );
    }

    return Adj;
}
```

The problems:

1. If the weight of the edges is equal to 1, as declared into the getMatrixWeight function, A* take strange paths, like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z80GM.png 
   if the weight of the edges is > 1, A* works correctly (not all the time, but 99%)
2. A* seems to get into a loop if the target isn't reachable. No problem for BFS and Dijkstra.
3. I implemented a little "utility" to monitor the performance of the scriprs. BFS and Dijkstra works fine( BFS is a little faster than Dijkstra, but it maybe depends by the Heap implementation, i Think).
   But it seems that A* is from 10 to 30 times slower, as you can see from the image! So I think that there is something wrong into the implementation, but I can't find what the problem is (and maybe it's connected with the point 2: the loop)!

I think the other functions ( sets and heap implementation, neighbor implementation) works fine, because BFS and Dijkstra have no problems.

If you would like to see the rest of the code, it's here: repo:https://bitbucket.org/ozeta86/labirinto/src

Answer (score 1):

First you have an initialisation problem, as you `push ( closed , setInt ( x ) );` but x is not initialized the first time you do this.  But that isn't the cause of the issue.

Reading your code, I understand that your implementation of A* as follows:

- f[i] is the best estimated cost for node i.
- g[i] is the cumulated distance of path that lead to node i
- you claculate g[y], the prolongation of the path from x to y by adding the extra weight.
- that cost is then calculated by usging the cumulated distance of the path plus the heuristic remaining to target.

The problem is that your g[] cumulates not the distance of one path, but of all the pathes that are explored. If several pathes use the same node, you will have a meaningless g.

In other words, for any path arriving at i you try to expand, g[i] will not contain the unique distance of the path up to i (requirement for A* in order to calculate a meaninful cost) but unpredictable values which depend on the previous path that were explored.

Hence the eratic result.

You have to change your data structure, in order to store the distance of your path on the heap together with your path, so that at next attempt to expand it you'll use the real distance corresponding to this path.

Comment: Hi @Christophe, I fixed the push line and I kinda understood the problem, but I didn't fully comprehend what you mean for _store the distance of your path on the heap together with your path_. Can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry, not on the heap, i meant in the sorted queue. When you insert you've to store also the distance in order to calculate accurately distance at rhe next path extension

Comment: If you don't want to save g together with the path, there is an alternative of calculating a tentative_g and update g only if it's smaller. Pseudocode for this second approach can be found in english wikipedia article on a star.

Comment: I don't get it...Updating g if smaller that's not what I do in the first If case?

`if ( yInOpen && cost < f[y] ) { // case 1
    decreaseKey ( open, y, cost );
}`

Comment: In the while loop processîg adjacency list you've definitively an unconditional g[y]=g[x]+...

Comment: mhh, ok. Tomorrow I'll work on the code and I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1):

I used another implementation, now this works and have a good performance, compared to BFS and dijkstra. I used [Introduction to A* from Red Blob Games](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html)

```
int *a_star ( GRAPHOBJ *graph, int s, int t ) {

    int i;
    int current;
    bool found              = false;
    void    *   tmp;                    //used to store Heap first element
    Set     *   AdjList     = NULL;     //Adjiacence list implemented as queue
    Heap    *   frontier    = NULL;     //Open set implemented as Heap
    frontier                = initializeHeap ( minHeapify );
    int     *   came_from   = ( int *) malloc ( graph->vNum * sizeof ( int ) );
    int     *   cost_so_far = ( int *) malloc ( graph->vNum * sizeof ( int ) );


    //initialization
    for ( i = 0; i < graph->vNum; i++ ) {
        came_from[i]    = NIL;
        cost_so_far[i]  = INFINITE;
    }
    insert ( frontier, new_HeapData ( s, 0 ) );
    cost_so_far[s]  = 0;
    while ( !isHeapEmpty ( frontier ) ) {
        tmp     = extractFirst ( frontier );
        current = getData ( tmp );


        if ( current == t ) {
            break;
        }
        AdjList = graph->getAdjList ( graph, current );
        while ( !isEmpty ( AdjList ) ) {
            int y = getInt ( getFront ( AdjList ) );
            AdjList = dequeue ( AdjList );
            int new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + graph->getWeight ( graph, current, y );
            if ( cost_so_far[y] == INFINITE || new_cost < cost_so_far[y] ) {
                cost_so_far[y] = new_cost;
                int priority = new_cost + heuristic ( graph, y, t );
                insert ( frontier, new_HeapData ( y, priority ) );
                came_from[y] = current;
            }
        }
    }
    return came_from;
}
```